# Swift: entityForName: could not locate an entity named xxx in this model

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode7

I created a test project to fetch data from `http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/` everything works fine, but when I try to save the data returned by the web service to a data model entity named `ContactDB` by
`let rowDB = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(NSStringFromClass(ContactDB.self), inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! ContactDB` ,

I get this runtime crash:
`+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'TestAlamofire5.ContactDB' in this model`

I have tried every possible solution mentioned in all related posts in SO:
changed the entity name
prefixed the NSManagedOBject subclass with @objc attribute
deleted the entity and created a new one
deleted the whole data model and created a new one  with a new entity
cleaned the project or even created a new project

but to no avail ...

what am i doing wrong to get this crash ?

p.s. the test project [can be downloaded here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/TestAlamofire5.zip)

Comment: Did you simply try `insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ContactDB", ...` ?

Comment: oh this really worked !!!! but why ??

Comment: Because the method expects just the literal name of the entity and your type construction includes always also the module (`TestAlamofire5`) of the class.

Comment: oh I really didn't know that, please provide this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest - and expected - way is to pass the literal name of the entity.

```
let rowDB = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ContactDB", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! ContactDB
```

Comment: please mention the reason in answer also. As you mentioned it in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Also note Xcode can set the Module namespace automatically. I had to delete "Current Product Module" for my Entity to be recognised. [image: Xcode Module]